# loading xml application context ioexception spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm starting to learn the Spring framework and when i run the application i get an IOException saying that the xml file does not exist but it is located in the root folder. Here's the little code: package org.koushik.javabrains;

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DrawingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Triangle triangle = (Triangle)context.getBean("triangle");

        triangle.draw();

    }

}
```

The xml:

```
<beans>

<bean id="triangle" class="org.koushik.javabrains.Triangle">
    <property name="type" value="Equilateral"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Here's how the project looks like:

[image]

This worked perfectly when i used the BeanFactory interface but with the ApplicationContext i get this error. I tried putting the xml file i the src folder but it didn't work either. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the spring.xml in your src folder, not the root folder, as ClassPathXmlApplicationContext reads from the classpath.

Comment: thanks a lot, it seems that i put the spring.xml file in the package with the other classes instead of putting it in the src folder.